# Can I change the style of elements that are contained within an iframe that itself is contained in external HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a navigation menu contained in an `iframe` that itself is pulled from an external file:

```
<iframe src="iframe.htm"></iframe>
```

The contents of `iframe.htm`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>iframe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="index" href="index.htm" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="page01" href="page01.htm" target="_blank"> 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="page02" href="page02.htm" target="_blank"> 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="page03" href="page03.htm" target="_blank"> 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

The goal is provide user feedback by changing the background color and text color of the anchor of the page the user is currently visiting. So within `iframe.htm` for `id="index"` I can do:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('index').style.backgroundColor = 'sandybrown'; document.getElementById('index').style.color = 'black'">
```

My question: Is it possible to access elements in an iframe (from the *outside*) that itself is contained in external HTML through JavaScript in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (unless both pages are in same domain). You can use *contentDocument* property for example:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="iframe.htm"></iframe>
<script>
    var f = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    f.contentDocument.getElementById('index').style.backgroundColor = 'sandybrown';
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

No, its not possible to add any styling through JS or CSS to iframe code.

Comment: It is definitely possible. See my example.